# How to use multi-column option box within select element

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

we all know **Drop-down list** can have [mutli menus in drop down](https://codepen.io/dustlilac/pen/Qwpxbp?editors=1010) like this

I was trying to do the same using **select** element

```css
#otp2{
  margin-top:-100px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  
  <optgroup id="otp1" label="Category 1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup id="otp2"   label="Category 2">
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>
```

I tried to adjust it with the margins but none works. how to do it?

Is it possible in select option list?

Comment: Is it possible in select option list? no

Comment: You can use a hidden select option which selects what the user chooses on the div option using jqurey to change the select option. then you can style it any way you want

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer:

```
        <style>
        .selectedOrder {
            height: 30px; 
            display:none; 
        }

    /* class applies to select element itself, not a wrapper element */
    .select-css {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #444;
        line-height: 1.3;
        padding: .6em 1.4em .5em .8em;
        /* width: 100%; */
        max-width: 100%; /* useful when width is set to anything other than 100% */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
        border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        /* note: bg image below uses 2 urls. The first is an svg data uri for the arrow icon, and the second is the gradient. 
            for the icon, if you want to change the color, be sure to use `%23` instead of `#`, since it's a url. You can also swap in a different svg icon or an external image reference
            
        */
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'),
          linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
        /* arrow icon position (1em from the right, 50% vertical) , then gradient position*/
        background-position: right .7em top 50%, 0 0;
        /* icon size, then gradient */
        background-size: .65em auto, 100%;
    }
    /* Hide arrow icon in IE browsers */
    .select-css::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Hover style */
    .select-css:hover {
        border-color: #888;
    }
    /* Focus style */
    .select-css:focus {
        border-color: #aaa;
        /* It'd be nice to use -webkit-focus-ring-color here but it doesn't work on box-shadow */
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(59, 153, 252, .7);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px -moz-mac-focusring;
        color: #222; 
        outline: none;
    }

    /* Set options to normal weight */
    .select-css option {
        font-weight:normal;
    }

    /* Support for rtl text, explicit support for Arabic and Hebrew */
    *[dir="rtl"] .select-css, :root:lang(ar) .select-css, :root:lang(iw) .select-css {
        background-position: left .7em top 50%, 0 0;
        padding: .6em .8em .5em 1.4em;
    }

    /* Disabled styles */
    .select-css:disabled, .select-css[aria-disabled=true] {
        color: graytext;
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22graytext%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'),
          linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    }

    .select-css:disabled:hover, .select-css[aria-disabled=true] {
        border-color: #aaa;
    }
</style>

<div id="orderSelectContainer">
    <div id="selectedOrder" class="selectedOrder select-css" style="width: 533px; display: block;">
        <div class="currentSelectedOrder" data-value="45628" style="float: left;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 1</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55628</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px">  </span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="orderSelect" class="select-css" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; background-image: none; display: none;">
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45628" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 1</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55628</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px">  </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45536" style="float: left; background: lightblue;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 2</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55536</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px"> Bad UPCs</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45682" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 3</span><span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55682</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px"> Bad UPCs</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45625" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 4</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55625</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px">  </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45556" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 5</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55556</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px"> Bad UPCs</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both"><br>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on(`click`, `.order`, function() {
        if ($(this).data(`value`) !== $(`#selectedOrder >.currentSelectedOrder`).data(`value`)) {
            $(`#orderContainer`).html(``);
        }
        $(`#selectedOrder`).html($(this).prop(`outerHTML`)).find(`.order`).removeClass(`order`).css(`background`, ``).addClass(`currentSelectedOrder`);
        $(`.order`).css(`background`, `white`);
        $(this).css(`background`, `lightblue`);
        $(`#selectedOrder`).show();
        $(`#orderSelect`).hide();
    });

    $(document).on(`click`, `#selectedOrder`, function() {
        //$(`#selectedOrder`).hide();
        $(`#orderSelect`).toggle();
    });

    $(document).on(`mouseenter`, `.order`, function() {
        $(`.order`).css(`background`, `white`);
        $(this).css(`background`, `lightblue`);
    });

    $(document).on(`mouseexit`, `.order`, function() {
        $(this).css(`background`, `white`);
    });
<script>
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/schmidtc63/xu8zgpc9/

Answer (score -1):

No. Is not possible in CSS. However, i found this link that might help.

[HTML multiple column drop down with adjusted columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162219/html-multiple-column-drop-down-with-adjusted-columns)

Comment: I already googled this solution.Is it just space appended within single option. I need multi menu.

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. Please provide the important parts of that page here.