# Select Option Dropdown display two object properties and line them up

Tags: javascript, html, css

The values for my select option dropdown need to contain employee + title and be lined up.
For example if my values are:

```
Bob Smith Director  
Mike Kawazki HR
Jane Doe Manager
```

I want them to appear:

```
Bob Smith      Director  
Mike Kawazki   HR
Jane Doe       Manager
```

My current answer is similar to the accepted answer for this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162219/html-multiple-column-drop-down-with-adjusted-columns).
However that answer require a font styling to line up the text and I need to retain the font I'm using.

Comment: What font are you trying to use?

Comment: it's a custom company font

Comment: Can you link that font so I can troubleshoot it?

Comment: What is the name of it?

Comment: actually it looks like the default dropdown styling? i can't tell for sure but i can't change the font to the one used in the post i linked above (font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace)

Answer (score 0):

This works with this font:

```js
var spacesToAdd = 5;
var maxcharacters = 0;
var toadd = ""; //leave blank!! Or you could add like a -
const array = [];
function addv(num){
array[array.length] = num;
}
$("#timezones option").each(function(){
var parts = $(this).text().split('|');
var len = parts[0].length;
addv(len);
});
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, array);
$("#timezones option").each(function(){
    var parts = $(this).text().split('|');
    var strLength = parts[0].length;
    var strLength2 = parts[1].length;
    var larg = largest + spacesToAdd;
    var numm2;
    if(strLength == largest){
    numm2 = spacesToAdd;
    }else if(strLength < largest){
    numm2 = larg - strLength;
    }
    if(toadd == ''){
    toadd = '\u{A0}';
    }
    for(var x=0; x<(numm2); x++){
        parts[0] = parts[0]+'⇴'; 
    }
    $(this).text(parts[0].replaceAll("⇴", toadd)+parts[1]).text;
});
```

```css
#timezones{
    font-family:"Lora", monospace
}
option {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
option .l{
float: left;
}

option:before {
  content: ">";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

option:hover:before {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="timezones" id="timezones">
    <option value="1">Bob Smith | Director</option>
    <option value="2">Mike Kawazki | HR</option>
     <option value="3">Jane Doe | Manager</option>
</select>
```

Will this work for you?
just remove the Lora font and use the other font.

Change `toadd` to `"-"` if you want!
Make sure to add spaces around your `|` to break it from left to right.

Comment: your answer is similar to mine in that it uses font-family to change the font. I want the font to remain what it currently is